# Hibernate Envers: onPostInsert fired when object has not been saved yet

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

In my Java app I want to listen to the events when an object is persisted i.e added to the db. Then I use the id of this persisted object to perform some queries. This is the code

```
@Component
public class DataCreationListener extends EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    DataService DataService;

    public DataCreationListener() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {

        if (event.getEntity() instanceof DataDAO) {

            //Here I use the info from event.getEntity() to perform some queries.
            Data Data = DataService.fromDao((DataDAO) event.getEntity());
            // other stuff
        }
    }

}
```

But since the object for which the event has been fired has not been saved yet, the queries raise exceptions. If the listener name is `onPostInsert` I expect it to fire when an entry has already been made in the dB but that is not the case. Upon debugging I see that once the control flows out of the listener then the object gets saved.

Is there any way that I can get the desired functionality here i.e. get the listener to fire when the object is saved, or do it somehow myself in a reliable and safe way? Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks !!

Comment: try with FlushEventListener

Comment: using PersistEventListener worked !!

Comment: What you're looking for is a `BeforeTransactionCompletion` callback.